# JQuery append - multiple instances after removal

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I am attempting to create a modal window with jquery and seem to have done it fairly well. The only problem is when I click the contact button for the second time it seems to append two modal boxes. One on top of the other. And a third if clicked again....

Here is the code:

```
$('#contact').on( 'click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body').append('<div id="modal"></div>');
        $("#modal").load('/forms/contact-form.html').hide().fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $('#send').click(function(e){
        $('#modal').remove();
    });
```

Can someone please explain why this is happening? Also any feedback about what I am attempting here is welcome.

Comment: HTML ids have to be unique...

Comment: @user980988 Why are you adding and removing the modal and not hiding it? Not the best way to handle a modal unless there needs to be a few of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to remove modal div when you are creating new modal div.

```
$('#contact').on('click', function () {
    $('#modal').remove(); //remove modal here
    $('body').append('<div id="modal"></div>');
    $("#modal").load('/forms/contact-form.html').hide().fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  removing,before appneding.

```
$('#contact').on( 'click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#modal').remove();
        $('body').append('<div id="modal"></div>');
        $("#modal").load('/forms/contact-form.html').hide().fadeIn(1000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

After click, you should delete some modal boxes, that are showing on the page in that time. Sure, if some exists.

```
$('body').find("#modal").remove();
```

Or just short form:

```
$("#modal").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of `#send click` `#modal` is not removed because it is created dynamically, so try it by using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on)

```
$(document).on('click','#send',function(e){// jquery event delegation
    $('#modal').remove();// it will remove the dynamically created modal box
});
```

Alternatively you can use the code like,

```
$('#contact').on( 'click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!$('#modal').length)// append modal only if not present
       $('body').append('<div id="modal"></div>');
    $("#modal").load('/forms/contact-form.html').hide().fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Why

Your code is appending a new div each time the `#contact` element is clicked.
Therefore each time the button is clicked the browser is rendering a new modal window.

### Solution

Create the modal div only once and reuse it as a variable.
You can do this using the [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) method.

<kbd>[Here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/ifujuf/1)</kbd>

```
var $modal = false;

$('#contact').on( 'click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    if ( ! $modal ){

      $modal = $('<div id="modal"></div>').appendTo('body');

    }

    $modal.load('/forms/contact-form.html').hide().fadeIn(1000);

});

$('#send').click(function(e){

    if ( $modal )
      $modal.hide();

});
```